# MVVM two Viewmodel in single xaml file

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i am using one xaml file which contains two Panels(left panel, right panel). which means two views.
I am also using two ViewModel to each views. 
How to bind DataContext to this situation?

Answer (score 3):

You need each to have its own ViewModel. You probably already have a View with multiple ViewModels. Do you have an ItemControl that binds to List? I usually do.

I would create a ViewModel that has two properties.

```
public class ParentScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ViewModelBase LeftPanel 
    { 
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }

    public ViewModelBase RightPanel 
    { 
        get {...}
        set {...}
    }
}
```

Then the XAML would bind to these:

```
<Panel x:Name="LeftPanel" DataContext="{Binding LeftPanel}" />
<Panel x:Name="RightPanel" DataContext="{Binding RightPanel}" />
```

Anyway, that is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the DataContext on any child element in the treeview.

Otherwise said, set both panels to their respective DataContext - it will take precendence over the parent container's (such as the window or usercontrol) datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g. two StackPanel, try this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spFirst" />

<StackPanel x:Name="spSecond" />
```

And in code-behind:

```
FirstViewModel vm1 = new FirstViewModel();

SecondViewModel vm2 = new SecondViewModel();

spFirst.DataContext = vm1;

spSecond.DataContext = vm2;
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/SN1iLs) you have example (DoubleDataContextExample.zip).

Comment: i tried this, but it is not working. i could not able to set view model to stack panel.

Comment: @Lakshmanan I created example for you, it's in the bottom in my answer.